# Border right and bottom different color

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm facing an issue with styles on IE 10. I apply a style on a table cell within angular with:

```
<td class="viseeColumns" data-ng-repeat="fdata in ProjectedData" data-ng-class="$index == ProjectedData.length - 1 ? 'borderWitheRight10' : ''">&nbsp;</td>
```

I just want the right border to be white and the bottom border to be black.
On Chrome it's good, but IE draws a diagonal line.

Is there a way to do this on IE (like Chrome)?

Comment: Show us the generated markup, without the `angularjs` bits.

Comment: I put your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/nx033zyh/1/), but I don't see anything. And if I add the borders that I think you mean, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/nx033zyh/2/) then there's no difference between the browsers.

Comment: Yes Mr Lister like your jsfiddle but in white like it makes like this : http://jsfiddle.net/9fs9duky/1/ Edit: it seems like it doesn't make it in simple table. Edit n°2 : get it my bottom border is 1 px, there you can see it in chrome vs ie.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ph7jm7v/1/ with the 1 px bottom

Comment: With zoom i can see the diagonal, but without zoom i can't see it on chrome. But IE i see the diagonal even without zoom. Anyway is it possible have black on bottom and white on the right side without this diagonal ?

Comment: Finally i had a conditionnal <td> in my table thanks